# Which of these words are attributes?

Tags: adjective, genitive, infinitive, grammar-identification

My son (in a Gymnasium in Germany) had some homework today that stumped me.  He has to identify the *[Attribute](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribut_(Grammatik))* in a set of sentences.  Some of them were easy:

> Plötzlich hören sie im Keller des Hauses merkwürdige Geräusche.

Going by the Wikipedia article I've linked above, in this sentence, *des Hauses* would be a *Substantivgruppe als Genitivattribut* modifying *Keller*, and *merkwürdige* would be an *Adjektiv* attribute modifying *Geräusche*.

But this one left me quite puzzled:

> Da sieht er die Katze der Nachbarn verschreckt in der Ecke sitzen.

Clearly *der Nachbarn* is another *Substantivgruppe als Genitivattribut* modifying *die Katze.*  I'm up in the air about the rest.

I would guess that *verschreckt* can't modify *die Katze* due to its position.  I would also guess that *sitzen* is a verb, not an attribute.

But what about *in der Ecke*?  Can it modify *die Katze*, or must it modify *sitzen*, and why?  And how exactly would one describe what *sitzen* does in this sentence?

Comment: *Verschreckt* modifies the finite verb *sitzen*. There's a hell of a difference between *sitzen* and *verschreckt sitzen*. *In der Ecke* is the place where something happens, as *im Keller des Hauses* is in the other example.

Comment: Oh no... do they still abuse children in school with this nonsensical form of grammar? I had hoped this had gone down the river of history...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, my son is not a native German speaker, and the whole year has been like this.  The school said they'd teach him German; apparently sitting through crap like this is how they intended to do it.  Needless to say, he'll be in a different school next year...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann why would this be nonsense grammar? Is it the teaching method you oppose to, or the grammatical analysis?

Comment: @Beta. I call it nonsensical because I do not see the sense (or use) of it. - My background: I spent 7 years as a newspaper editor in a German daily, so I would call myself a professional German language practicioner, and I studied linguistics (based on slavonic languages), so I might call myself also to some degree a linguist. I find analysing the structure of language(s) extremely interesting and important for the intellectual development of the individual, but I never saw any use of *this specific* form of analysis which is being taught in German schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a very strict sense, everything that goes with the predicate of a sentence (or rather *how* something happens) is **not** considered an attribute.

Attributes are additions to components of the sentence (subject, object,...) that qualify or modify these components.

A good test for an attribute, at least for most non-complicated sentences,  is: If you move the component that you suspect is qualified by the (suspected) attribute, the attribute moves together with it and does **not** change its relative position to the component.

> Die *Katze der Nachbarin* sitzt verschreckt in der Ecke.

vs.

> In der Ecke sitzt verschreckt *die Katze der Nachbarin*

strong hint towards "der Nachbarin" is an attribute, "verschreckt" is none.

Slightly different:

> *Die verschreckte Katze der Nachbarin* sitzt in der Ecke.

vs.

> In der Ecke sitzt *die verschreckte Katze der Nachbarin*

both "verschreckt" and "der Nachbarin* moved together with the subject, so both are attributes.

Both "in der Ecke" and "verschreckt" in your sentence qualify the predicate.

So, in your second original sentence, only "der Nachbarin" would be considered an attribute.

Comment: It wasn't "Mrs Neighbour" (die Nachbarin), but the Neighbours ( die Nachbarn) in the example, but that's of course of little importance

Comment: If one wanted "in der Ecke" to qualify the _cat_, how would one do it?  _Can_ one do it?  In English I could say something like "The cat in the corner sat frightened."

Comment: @Kyralessa you can do the same in German: "Die Katze in der Ecke saß verschreckt da."

Answer (score 2):

You already answered your own question with the wikipedia link you gave.
Here, we have one example for an attribute:

> Das **Bellen** *des Hundes* weckte mich.

In this example, "des Hundes" is an attribute, specifying "Bellen". Applying this to your sentence, we see that "der Nachbarn" is an attribute, specifying "Katze".

The word "verschreckt" specifies "sitzen" (as already stated, there is a strong difference between sitting and sitting teriffied) and is thus no attribute. To see that, look again at the wikipedia article you gave:

> Nur Begleiter eines Verbs werden nie als Attribute bezeichnet, weil dies genau die Elemente sind, die als Satzglieder bezeichnet werden.

This claims that words that go with verbs are never, ever considered attributes.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me what *verschreckt* and *in der Ecke* went with.  If it had been, I wouldn't have asked the question.